# How to show analytically $d(0,S)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $S$  be a subset of a metric space ($X,d$) & $p$ be any point of $X$.The distance between $p$ and $S$ is $d(p,S)$=inf{$d(p,x):x \in S$}.

Let $S=(0,1)$ & $p=0$ then the distance between $p $ & $S$ is given by $d(0,S)$=inf{$d(0,x):x \in S$}.

I'm getting the intuition that $d(0,S)=0$,but i'm unable to show this analytically.

Need Help

Comment: Try assuming for contradiction that $d(p,S) = \epsilon > 0$. Can you always provide a counterexample? Then note that $d(0, s) \geq 0$ by definition.

Comment: @J.Marx-Kuo:in particular if i take $x=1/n$,then $d(0,S)=$inf{$d(0,1/n):n \in \mathbb N$} $\implies$ $d(0,S)$=inf{$d(0,1/n):n \in \mathbb N$} $\implies d(0,S)$= inf{$1/n:n \in \mathbb N$}=0.

Comment: @J.Marx-Kuo:Is it correct?

Comment: Though true, I don't think you want to say

$$d(0, S) = \inf\{d(0, 1/n) \; : \; n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

I think you're really making a statement about the $\inf$ of a subset $E \subset S$. In general if we have a function $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$, then for $E \subset S$ the following is true

$$\inf\{f(x) \; : x \in S\} \leq \inf\{ f(x) \; : \; x \in E\}$$

Comment: In the context of this problem you must say that 

$$d(0, S) \leq d(0, E)$$

where $E = \{1/n\}_{n = 2}^{\infty}$. From here you should be more formal in your proof by showing that $0 \leq d(0, E) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$, which implies

$$0 \leq d(0, S) \leq d(0, E) \leq 0$$

which is only true if $d(0, S) = d(0, E) = 0$.